# Woocommerce - Apply 10% discount to the lowest priced product in the cart based on several conditions

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm struggled with one problem and the problem is as it follows. In our store users could create a package from 3 products. I need to apply a 10% discount to 2 products in cart.

1. PRODUCT required to get a discount = 10 euros
2. PRODUCT = 15 euros - you could get a discount from this product
3. PRODUCT = 12 euros - you could get a discount from this product

Discount should apply always to required product and the lowest price product 2 or 3.

Cart examples

- If there is product 1, 2 and 3 in cart you will get a 10% discount to product number 1 and product number 3.
- If there is a product number 1 and 3 in cart you will get a 10% discount to the both of them
- If there is a product number 1 and 2 in cart you will get a 10% discount to the both of them
- If there is a product number 1 only, product number 2 only, product number 3 only, then no discount is applied to your cart
- If there is some of the combinations and other products which are not these 3 mentioned products above, the discount will be applied only for the mentioned products as it follows from cart examples above.
- If there are more sets - if you want to order 2 products from (product number 1 and product number 2) or (product number 1 and product number 3) you have to add always 1 more to the both of them to get another 10% sale from another set so quantity will be 2/2. If theres quantity 2 (ID1)/1 (ID2) no discount will be applied for the second set only for the first one.

My code so far but I'm totally lost

```
function apply_discount_ten( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // Product ID needs to be in cart to get a discount
    $product_id = 2530;

    // Products in cart
    $products_in_cart = count( $cart->get_cart() );
    
    //Set conditions
    if ( $products_in_cart && (matched_cart_items($product_id)) {
       
       // Set array
        $product_prices = array();

        // Loop though cart items
        foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
       
            // Product
            $product = $cart_item['data'];

            // Get price
            $product_price = $product->get_price();

            // Push
            $product_prices[] = $product_price;
        }

        // Sort: low to high
        asort( $product_prices );

        // Number of products receive a discount
        $products_receive_discount = What to do here;

        // Set variable
        $total = 0;

        // Loop trough
        foreach ( array_slice( $product_prices, 0, $products_receive_discount ) as $product_price ) {
            // Calculate
            $total += $product_price;
        }

        // Calculate discount
        $discount = ( $total * 10 ) / 100;

        // Add fee
        $cart->add_fee( 'Discount', $discount, true );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'apply_discount_ten', 10, 1 );
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: There is rather little point in pushing only the product prices into an array and then sorting that - now you know what the lowest price is (or are, if two or more products have the same prices and it is the lowest), but you don't know which product it belonged to in the first place. You could f.e. use the product ID as array key, and then go get the first element of the sorted array afterwards.

Comment: (But if you don't exclude products cheaper than 5 Euros from your array to begin with, you can not just pick the first item out of the sorted array, you would then need to loop & compare again, until you find the first one inside the sorted array, that fulfills all criteria.)

Comment: @CBroe could you help me with it if you have a time?

Comment: You are using the wrong hook, because it serves to add a fee, it is also sometimes (incorrectly) used for a discount by applying it as a negative fee, but that is actually not recommended. 
So if you want to effectively change product prices you have to use a different hook. 
A question: what if some products in the cart have the same lowest price?

Comment: I was thinking about the other method which is more effective I updated my question.

Comment: @7uc1f3r check on my updated question, it gives much more logic now